# Контекст исполнения this

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с неким непониманием принципа работы JavaScript заключенный в следующем: у ссылки `<A>` отсутствует контекст `this`. Искал в поисковике информацию, но не получилось.

```
<SPAN onclick="alert(this);">test</SPAN><BR/>
<A onclick="alert(this);">test2</A>
```

Оно же на [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/Qr2wh/).
Как можно получить доступ к this ссылки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<SPAN onclick="alert(this);">test</SPAN><BR/>
<A onclick="alert(this.href);" href='abc'>test2</A>
```

Все пашет. И пашет неплохо.

UPD: видимо, a не умеет существовать без уточняющего атрибута. 
Если в указанном примере вызвать alert(this), тоже выдаст ссыль.

Comment: Вот поэтому не понял я источника проблемы

​    a=document.createElement("a");
    a.href="asdaf";
    alert(a);​
Ссылка при конвертировании в строку становится просто адресом на которую она ведет. В моем примере пустая строка.

Comment: просто, как я понимаю:

     a.toString = function() {
       return this.href;
     }

Так что все нормально работает

Comment: > UPD: видимо, a не умеет существовать без уточняющего атрибута.

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Tq27w.jpg

Comment: Ilya Pirogov, вместо этой картинки можно было разместить исчерпывающее объяснение как причины размещения картинки, так и указанного "феномена". ;)

Comment: @knes - да я же вам написал -_-

Comment: @AlexWindHope, это я прочел. Но при этом я все равно не врубился в недовольство Ильи.

Comment: @knes - ну захотелось человеку немного потролить :D

Comment: @knes, что вы, никакого недовольства. Наоборот повеселили :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<A onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">test2</A>
```

Работает нормально

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вам просто нужно почитать про метод [`toString()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_boolean.asp).  [Пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr2wh/2/)

Так же для отладки вместо alert'а лучше пользоваться методом `console.log()`.

Comment: Я привык к тому, что конвертация узлов DOM происходит обычно к виду  
`<ELEMENT nodeTagName>`  
Похоже все элементы кроме A конвертируются по такому принципу и в этом я словил коварность.  
Мне раньше казалось, что приводя пример на jsfiddle более наглядно использовать alert, а не console.log, и это была моя вторая ошибка.